What is the correct way to get data for an EditForm using EF Core, with or without tracking?
I have a Blazor EditForm and I use Model to relate it to the object and to bind the controls.
EditForm Model="@Client" OnValidSubmit="SubmitForm"
I use EF Core to bring the data from the model when the user wants to edit it,
var Client = _dbContext.Set().FindAsync(id);
However, when the user enters to edit a Client and changes a piece of data, but then leaves the form without saving it by no pressing the save button, if he returns to the form to edit the same record, the field that was modified without saving shows the data that the user had captured, this is because of the tracking that EF Core does.
If I change my code to
var client = _dbContext.Set().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClientId == id),
EF Core no longer does the tracking and that solves the problem.
What I would like to know is if doing this is correct and if it affects the performance of my system.
Thank you.

I don't know a lot about blazor, but it seems you're missing a layer? I wouldn't let the client directly edit the db.

I am using a repository but for simplicity I didn't put the code

I mean normally you have a layer which represents your view. The view loads a model wich differs from your entity. this way the model is detached from ef change tracking, which is good because you never know when the client closes the browser.

Ok Kevin I understand what you mean, and when you read data from the database with ef core in a scenario like this do you typically use AsNoTracking?

There's a lot of content on the web on how to use EF in blazor apps. Please try to get the full picture before making decisions based on this narrow scenario. It's not hard, but nevertheless too broad to cover here.

@LuisZenteno you could use AsNoTracking() . as official document suggest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries  the entities retrieved from the database don't need to be updated, then a no-tracking query should be used. as you are  just display data for editing without saving the data this approach will be good and it is fast and give you good performance even with large data

Hi Jalpa thanks for your response, just to clarify, sometimes the user will update the data and sometimes he won't, so the question arises as to whether or not it is correct to use AsNoTracking just to avoid the scenario where the user does not save the data but then returns to the same record and sees what he previously captured and it may give him the impression that the record has already been saved when it has not.

@LuisZenteno in that case IServiceScopeFactory as suggested in the post that will help you. otherwise AsNoTracking() will provide the current state of the data as stored in the database, so it does not make any confusion for user.

You are facing a few challenges:
It’s very likely that you’ve registered DbContext as scoped, which is correct, but Blazor does not automatically create scopes. This is why the documentation emphasizes using IDbContextFactory.
However, working with IDbContextFactory can complicate repository usage since every method needs to create and dispose of a context.
In your case, having one DbContext per user session leads to conflicts with other operations triggered by the same session.
If you prefer not to manage IDbContextFactory and DbContext resources manually (this is subjective), here are two options:
Less ideal: Clear the DbContext state before each use: context.ChangeTracker.Clear().
Much better: Inject IServiceScopeFactory into your controller to manually create a scope. When you need to work with services or repositories, use CreateScope(), retrieve the required service, execute the desired method, and dispose of the scope.
Here’s a simplified example in C#:
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyController(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void SomeControllerMethod()
    {
        // Any services or repositories registered with scope lifetime will be disposed of automatically
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var someService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeService>();
        someService.DoSomeWork();
    }
}


Thank you very much Svyatoslav I'm gonna check on the concept of IDbContextFactory in order to understand the solution you give.
